# include first and last groups in query results

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following ERD

[image]

`assessment` represents a test completed by a user. Each assessment consists of a number of items, and `level` indicates their score on each.

I need to calculate the difference between the user's average score on their earliest and latest assessment, but I'm really struggling.

I can get the average score for each assessments with

```
SELECT a.user_id,
  a.date_created,
  avg(ai.level)
FROM assessment a
  JOIN assessment_item ai ON a.id = ai.assessment_id
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.date_created
ORDER BY 1;
```

This query returns data such as

```
user_id, date_created,          avg_score
10,      "2015-07-13 18:09:59", 3.0000
11,      "2015-07-13 18:09:59", 3.0000
13,      "2015-07-13 18:26:00", 2.0000
13,      "2015-07-13 18:27:28", 6.0000
13,      "2015-07-13 19:04:58", 3.0000
```

I could (programatically) iterate over the results returned by this query ignoring any "middle" assessments or results from users that have only completed one assessments, but I think there should be a way to improve the query such that the data it returns is closer to what I need.

Comment: can you post a sql fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT user_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(levavg order by date_created), ',', 1) as first_avg,
       substring_index(group_concat(levavg order by date_created desc), ',', 1) as lasst_avg,
FROM (SELECT a.user_id, a.date_created, avg(ai.level) as levavg
      FROM assessment a JOIN 
           assessment_item ai
           ON a.id = ai.assessment_id
      GROUP BY a.user_id, a.date_created
     ) ua
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I need, but it includes results from users that have only completed one assessment and there's no way for me to tell if they really have multiple assessments with the same average score or just one assessment. Is it possible to add the assessment count to the query?

Comment: @AntonioDragos . . . If you just want users with multiple assessments, then  add a `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` tot the rescue! (the first record has no previous record; the last record has no next record; exits yields a boolean, which can be compared)

[untested, since I have no test data]

```
SELECT a.user_id
  , a.date_created
  , avg(ai.level)
FROM assessment a
JOIN assessment_item ai ON a.id = ai.assessment_id
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM assessment xx
                WHERE xx.user_id = a.userid
                AND xx.date_created < a.date_created
                )
        <> EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM assessment xx
                WHERE xx.user_id = a.userid
                AND xx.date_created > a.date_created
                )
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.date_created
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```